# Sveltekit enabling csr when using throw for 404 from page.js

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have disabled csr in the root layout using the below code and all pages are rendering from the server itself without any issues. I don't have any csr or ssr settings in any other pages to make sure the whole app is SSR

```
export const csr = false;
```

With the above setup, when I request a URL for which a route not exists, the 404 page is getting loaded from the server without any client-side rendering. But when I load any page and from the page js file if I use the below code, it's switching to client-side rendering and all pages from then get loaded from the client side.

```
throw error(404, 'Not found');
```

I added +error.svelte page in root and the respective folders, but there is no change.

Sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-unjhsk?file=src/routes/+layout.server.js